# Add fragments to Tab host

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

How to use a **tabhost** in android to **control fragments**.i have one activity and four  Fragements and its corresponding xml files.i add my tab host in main_layout_activity.xml file.there i have another Linnerlayout i want to replace this linnerlayout from  Fragement.to replace these  Fragements i have to use tabhost.help me please? i've found one code but its  messy.please find below the code.

```
final TabHost tabs= (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
  tabs.setup();

  TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");
  spec.setContent(R.id.fragment1);
  spec.setIndicator("View Raves");
  tabs.addTab(spec);
  spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
  spec.setContent(R.id.fragment2);
  spec.setIndicator("My Badges");
  tabs.addTab(spec);
  tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
```

after having lot of ideas i do correct my code as following.pls find below

```
MainActivity.java

package com.example.testtabs;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import com.example.testtabs.R;




public class MainActivity extends TabActivity  {


 TabHost tab;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     FragementTest testfrag=new FragementTest();
  FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction transacti
  transaction.add(R.id.my_layout1, testfrag, "");
  transaction.commit();


    tab= (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tab.setup();

 }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:c 
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
         android:orientati >

    </LinearLayout>

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientati >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >


            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Craete a method like this and pass your tab data like its view,its name and Its fragment class..

```
/**
 * Used to create a tab
 * 
 * @param view
 * @param tag
 * @param name
 */
private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag, Class<?> name) {
        View tabview = createTabView(this, tag);
        TabSpec setContent = tabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview)
            .setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
                public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                    return view;
                }
            });
    tabHost.addTab(setContent, name, null);
}



/**
 * Used to create tabview object and setting parameters
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param text
 * @return
 */
private View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,
            null);
    Button _button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.tabText);
    _button.setText(text);
    return view;
}
```

And call that method like this..

```
setupTab(new Button(this), "Tab1", Fragment1.class);
setupTab(new Button(this), "Tab2", Fragment2.class);
```

Comment: i want to use final TabHost tabs= (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost); but my xml file "android:id="@android:id/tabhost" how it see then i couldnt intiated tab host are there any ideas? please

Comment: you can get tabhost object like this..tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

Comment: can you please explain what  new Button(this) does.in tabhost there we have tabwidget i have to add content to these tab widgets not to buttons.

Comment: its just one tab view like tab1 is one button and tab2 is another button..you can set text to that button whatever you want..

Comment: i have edited my answer you can set text to tabs what you want to display check it..

Comment: please find above my edited code.there i have posted my all code.now im working with my code and try to add your code.thank you very much

Comment: here is example project on tabActivity with fragments https://github.com/albertopenas/TabFragment

Comment: this is for tabs with fragmentTabHost https://github.com/colaboy2004/FragmentTabHostExample

Comment: there he used ActionBar i have to Use Tabhost.sorry i didnt help me.anyway thank you.

Comment: @kalyanpvs Are you using `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost` ?

Comment: @kalyanpvs I'm also having one main activity and three fragments with bottom tab buttons(I used one library for this). Here, I'm having listview for two fragments. One for search fragment and another one for favourite. If I add my fragments by add method. Then it calls each time when I click the tab button. So my listview state changes automatically and it begins with first list item. I need to save listitem. Help me please.. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is "tab_layout" in this scope?